# What can use instead CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest?

Tags: ios, cfnetwork, cfnetworking

This method CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest(...) was deprecated for IOS 9 and younger.

Docs of Apple suggests to use NSURLSession instead of this. But I don't understand how  I can reintegrate functionality which works with Live (I use stream) by NSURLSession.

I don't see any possibility for load "live" by NSURLSession.

What do you use for load live data by special url from server?